# Googlemap custom infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is there a way to create custom infowindow in new API V3 of googlemaps.

If yes is there any example available?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Below Accepted  Answer Link is Not Found So, Please Again Update the Answer. from Your Side

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes. [Here](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html) is example.

Comment: Above Link is Not Found Please Share the New Link